# string outputting weird characters

Tags: c++, string, function, symbols

I have a function which takes a string and converts it into ASCII characters. However, when I try to store this output in a string, I get weird symbols such as this: "└└    " when I output it.

```
int returnval(char x)
{
    return (int)x - 96;
}

void getWord(string wordRecieved)
{
    cout << wordRecieved << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < wordRecieved.length(); i++)
    {

        std::string final;

        final = returnval(wordRecieved[i]);

        cout << final;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood how character encoding works. If `x` is a character, `(int) x` is the value in its encoding. If it's an ASCII character, `x - 96` is its distance from the backtick character.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this code also turns the ASCII into the numbers of letters in the alphabet e.g. 1 = a. So the ASCII code for a normally would be 97 but minus the 96 gives it a value of 1.

Comment: The ASCII code for `'a'` *is* 97. Not normally, but always. The numbers from 1 to 26 all encode unprintable characters in ASCII, which is why you see weird things when you try to interpret them as characters..

Comment: `final = returnval(...)` makes a string from a number, but it doesnt make an `a` from a `1`. You invented your own encoding but implemented only one way and assumed the other way will work by magic

Comment: How would you suggest storing the output of the numbers? I thought the string would act as a container for the output. If I write cout << returnval(...), the output would be numbers and not random characters.

Comment: @Oxic The string does act as container, interpreting your numbers as character encodings in whatever is the current encoding. SInce the first printable character is most likely number 32 (space in ASCII), no characters below 128 will produce anything meaningful. (Unfortunately, the highest ASCII character is 127...)

Comment: Is there a way to store this to output it later?

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve? I think you get desired output if you just remove `returnval`, but I suppose thats not what you want

Comment: please post a [mcve] including input, output and expected output

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are doing some kind of encription. I try to suggest you a solution, but I am not sure it is your desire.

I suggest to convert int return from `returnval` into a string, and appended to the your string `final`. But this will generate a string cannot tell each coded character, therefore a delimiter (space) will be added after each character. You may change the delimiter to the character of your convinience.

A simple modification to your function `getWord`:

```
void getWord(string wordRecieved)
{
    std::string final;
    cout << wordRecieved << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < wordRecieved.length(); i++)
    {
        final += to_string( returnval(wordRecieved[i]) ) + " ";
    }
    std::cout << final <<std::endl;
}
```

Giving an input string `"abcdefghijklmn"`, it will print:

```
abcdefghijklmn
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```